# Why does returning a string slice instead of a usize prevent mutating a String?

Tags: rust

This code compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("some_string");
    let n = f1(&s);
    s.clear();
    println!("n = {}", n);
}

fn f1(s: &String) -> usize {
    10
}

fn f2(s: &String) -> &str {
    "def"
}
```

However, replacing the call to `f1()` by `f2()` causes a compilation failure. It appears to me that both `f1()` and `f2()` do an immutable borrow, and `s.clear()` does a mutable borrow, so I should get compilation error in both cases. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue:

```
fn f1(s: &String) -> usize { unimplemented!() }

fn f2(s: &String) -> &str { unimplemented!() }

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("some_string");
    let n = f1(&s);
    s.clear();
    println!("n = {}", n);
}
```

---

**Lifetime analysis is performed based on function signatures.**

You will note in the above code that I have used `unimplemented!()` as the body of the functions, and the problem is exactly the same. This is *normal*.

In the vast majority of cases<sup>1</sup>, a function signature fully specifies the interface of a function, and it is unnecessary to look at its implementation.

As a corollary, this also means that whether the lifetime in a return type is linked to the lifetime in any of the arguments is fully specified within the signature, and in this case the full signature of `f2` is therefore:

```
fn f2<'a>(s: &'a String) -> &'a str;
```

Whether the implementation of `f2` is `"def"` (with the `'static` lifetime) or `&*s` (with the `'a` lifetime) does not matter; only the signature matters, and the signature uses the same lifetime due to the elision rules.

<sup>1</sup> *The one exception I know of concerns the `-> impl Trait` feature and whether the resulting object implements `Send` or `Sync`.*

---

In the case of `f1`, the return type is not linked to the argument, therefore the borrow of the argument ends at the end of the call to `f1`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("some_string");
    let n = {
        //  Immutable borrow of s starts here.
        f1(&s)
        //  Immutable borrow of s ends here.
    };
    s.clear();
    println!("n = {}", n);
}
```

In the case of `f2`, the return type has the same lifetime as the argument, and therefore is considered to extend the borrow. In Rust 2015, the borrow would extend until the return value went out of scope (lexical borrow); with Rust 2018, the borrow extends until the last use of the return value (non-lexical borrow).

In your case, both are basically identical:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("some_string");
    let n = {
        //  Immutable borrow of s starts here.
        f2(&s)
    };
    s.clear();  //  Conflicting attempt to mutably borrow s.
    println!("n = {}", n);
    //  Immutable borrow of s ends here.
}
```

You could observe the difference by switching the order of `s.clear()` and `println!`.

Answer (score 3):

The Rust reference [says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html):

> If there is exactly one lifetime used in the parameters (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.

This means that your method

```
fn f2(s: &String) -> &str {
    "def"
}
```

is interpreted by Rust as:

```
fn f2<'a>(s: &'a String) -> &'a str {
    "def"
}
```

Since `"def"` has the lifetime `'static`, its lifetime can be shortened to `'a` when being returned from the function (so the compiler won't complain here), but when calling the function the compiler cannot infer that the true lifetime of the string was really `'static`. To do this, you must explicitly mark it as `'static` yourself:

```
fn f2(s: &String) -> &'static str {
    "def"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`f1` and `f2` both take an immutable borrow. However, the lifetime of the borrow from `f1` ends at the end of `f1`, because you're just returning a `usize` and not anything from the actual string.

However, `f2` returns a `&str`, which is borrowing your underlying `String`, `s`. Since `n` stays alive, the immutable borrow of `s` continues until `n` is no longer used. Effectively, this prevents your call to `s.clear()` from "pulling the rug out from under" your pointer `s`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a further question. Since f2() returns a string literal that is not related to `s`, does the compiler 'assume' that a return type of string slice means the underlying string is still referenced?

Comment: Yes. `rustc` does not look inside your function when attempting to guess lifetimes. Instead, it simply uses the signature. So it is (overly aggressively) thinking that your static string slice from `f2` borrows `s`, even though it doesn't. You could produce the desired behavior by explicitly specifying the lifetimes: `fn f2<'a>(s: &'a str) -> 'static str`